# Why I am getting undefined on web page?

Tags: javascript, json, function, if-statement

I am trying to display user status in the Gantt chart. But it returns undefined.

In this picture it is returning undefined and something else

[image].

I am using this method to return output

```
 var stat = groups.push(document.getElementsByClassName('status')); 
 var st = document.write(stat);
```

But it shows undefined and some server data instead of displaying 'Active' or 'Pause'

```js
function userStatus(online) {
  const element = document.querySelector('.status');
  if (online) {
    element.classList.remove('offline');
    element.classList.add('online');
    element.innerText = 'Activ';
  } else {
    element.classList.remove('online');
    element.classList.add('offline');
    element.innerText = 'Pause';
  }
}
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  userStatus(navigator.onLine);
  window.addEventListener('online', () => {
    userStatus(true);
  });
  window.addEventListener('offline', () => {
    userStatus(false);
  });
});
```

```css
.app {
  height: 4.7vh;
  width: 4.7vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin-left: 0.4px;
}

.status {
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 2.5%;
}

.status.online {
  color: #41a700;
}

.status.offline {
  color: #f15c4f;
}

.app {
  margin-left: 261px;
}

.app {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <h5 class="status">User Status</h5>
</div>
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) - I tried to format your question for you

Comment: I am not sure where you do `var stat = groups.push(document.getElementsByClassName('status')); 
 var st = document.write(stat);` but a push only returns a length. The two statements you mention are not in the code you show

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: Show the complete code and explain how to reproduce your error

Comment: I have removed push and everything else now i did this:                           var stat = document.getElementsByClassName('status');
 console.log(stat);                         On console it's showig write output but inside chart it is display undefined.   The project on which i am working is this             https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/examples/timeline/other/groupsPerformance.html                            .   Visit this site and below "Trucks" I want to show online or offline status.

Comment: It is javascript data visualization library and you can remove links on <head> with these cdn    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/almende/vis/master/lib/DataSet.js"></script>   <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://unpkg.com/vis-timeline@latest/standalone/umd/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.js"></script> then it will run prefectly.

Comment: I am still getting undefined and I have also removed document.write from my code. I am selecting class and console logging it.

Comment: You need to change `var stat = document.getElementsByClassName('status')` to `var stat = document.getElementsByClassName('status').textContent;`

Comment: I did same still getting undefined

Comment: This is a project on which i am working below truck i want to display user status(online or offline)       https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/